Upgraded OWIN libraries from version 3.0.1 to 4.2.0 Http RequestUri is coming in capital later
After upgrading the OWIN libraries from version 3.0.1 to 4.2.0, the Http RequestUri is now coming in capital letters. This means that if I am requesting from the front end like http://localhost/TestURL, then in the API backend, I am receiving the same URL. However, in the previous version, whatever URL I requested was always coming in lowercase, like http://localhost/testurl.
Upgraded libraries:
Microsoft.Owin: 3.0.1.0 => 4.2.2.0
Microsoft.Owin.Security: 3.0.1.0 => 4.2.2.0
I was looking for any documentation from OWIN but couldn't find any. Please help me provide any documentation from the OWIN side.
I am looking for documentation for URL casing from OWIN side.

I am also facing same issue

The path part of an URL is case sensitive. If a HTTP library converts it to lower case then this was a bug. Seem that in the recent versions this bug was fixed.
